# Division sign, not divergence

Tags: symbols, incompatibility, physics

Using \div gives me divergence sign instead of division (÷), for sure inside of math mode.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

$ 1 \div 2 $

\end{document}
```

returns back ;

[image]

As far as I know the problem is *physics* package and without it everything is ok, but I need it.

Comment: Could you post a full compilable example? I have nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably, the document is using package `physics`. It redefines the symbol for a different purpose. The old meaning of `\div` is saved in `\divisionsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\[ 1 \div 2 \]
\[ 1 \divisionsymbol 2 \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]